# How can we factor $ q^4 + q^2 + 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring

Alright, I met this example solved in a book, but I want to know how did they come up with the answer:

$$ (1+q^2+q^4) = (1+q^2+q)(1+q^2-q) $$

Can you also refer me some internet source where I can learn the rules of factoring. Thank you in advance.

Comment: here's something you may want to check and enjoy.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $ $  *completing* the square leads to a *difference* of squares, e.g.

$$\begin{eqnarray}\overbrace{q^4+1}^{\rm incomplete\ \large \Box\!\!}\!\!\! + q^2\!&\,=\,&\!\! \overbrace{(q^2+1)^2}^{\rm complete\ the\ \Large\Box \ \!\!\!}\!\!\!- \color{#c00}{q}^2\ \ \text{so, factoring this} \it\text{ difference of squares}\\
 &\,=\,& (q^2+1\,\ -\, \color{#c00}{q})\,(q^2+1+\,\color{#c00}{q})\\
\end{eqnarray}\qquad\quad\ \ \ $$ Here is another common example

$$\begin{eqnarray} n^4+4k^4 &\,=\,& \overbrace{(n^2\!+2k^2)^2}^{\rm\!\!\! complete\ the\ \large \Box\!\!\!}\!\!\!-\!(\color{#c00}{2nk})^2\ \ \text{so, factoring this} \it\text{ difference of squares}\\
 &\,=\,& (n^2\!+2k^2\ -\,\ \color{#c00}{2nk})\,(n^2\!+2k^2+\,\color{#c00}{2nk})\\
&\,=\,&(\underbrace{(n-k)^2}_{\rm\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! complete\ the\ \large \Box\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}\ +\ \,k^2)\ \ \underbrace{((n+k)^2}_{\rm\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! complete\ the\ \large \Box\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!} +\,k^2)\\ \end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$1+q^2+q^4=(1+q+q^2)(1+q^2-q)$$
Notice how $1^2=1$ and $(q^2)^2=q^4$, so $(1+q^2)^2$ will get us a few terms already:
$$(1+q^2)^2=1+q^4+2q^2$$
Hence:
$$1+q^2+q^4=(1+q^2)^2-q^2$$
Which is the difference of two squares, something we know we can factor:
$$1+q^2+q^4=(1+q^2)^2-q^2=((1+q^2)+q)((1+q^2)-q)=(1+q^2+q)(1+q^2-q)$$

---

Some often used rules for factoring are:
$$(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$$
$$(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$$
$$(a-1)(1+a+a^2+...+a^n)=a^{n+1}-1$$